# How do I browse a java/jQuery array of pairs?

Tags: java, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to use an array such as this to display questions and answers in a flashcard web app:

```
[{q: question1 , a:answer1}, {q:question2, a:answer2}...]
```

How can I create a function to browse through, i.e. display the next/previous question and answer?

Comment: Looks like you want a hash. You need to be searching for "java hash tutorial" at this point. Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please review the [Stack Overflow Help File](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on permitted topics on this site.

Comment: I'm sorry @MarsAtomic but I don't really understand why it isn't a good fit. It's concise, definitely answerable, as far as I can see it inspires answerers to explain 'why and how', it's not open-ended or ranty.

Comment: @inthevidual, jQuery is a JavaScript library, not Java. Also, while your question is concise and answerable, it doesn't show what you've attempted.

Comment: My objection was not only that the question covered a fundamental topic that you could have answered on your own with a simple web search, but that you did not include a [short, self contained, correct code example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrated whatever problem you encountered. Stack Overflow is meant to provide answers to *specific programming issues* rather than providing tutorial information.